# Present a subview outside superview's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, user-interface

I have a `UIView` that it's size is:

`Width` = Screen width, `Height` = 20% of the screen (a bar)

In it I have a couple of buttons, I've added each button a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and now the user can "throw" (drag to the middle) the icon and delete it (in the middle of a screen there's a trash can icon and when the user releases the button on the trash can it deletes the icon.

The problem is that when I drag the button it disappears after the bar (the superview) and not proceeding to drag in to the middle of the screen (it disappears at the end of the bar).

so my question is: How can I make a button visible outside its superview's bounds/frame?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: try `superView.clipsToBounds = false` or `masksToBounds = false`

Comment: @Tj3n I've tried `clipToBounds = false` and I didn't work. Can't find `maskToBounds` property

Comment: weird, `clipsToBounds` should allow you to show it's subview outside the view frame...maybe you should try add your subview on higher level view like `navigationController` view or in new window

Comment: @Tj3n Maybe that's because my view's layer is masked with a `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: try commented out that layer and see, also, `masksToBounds` is layer property, so it should be `view.layer.masksToBounds = false`, im not really good on graphical stuff so if it not work then i have no idea :D

Comment: @Tj3n removing the `view.layer.mask = myShapeLayer` solved the problem, but now my view isn't masked as I want it to be, any idea?

Comment: you can first create a ContainerView With The size Of The Screen With Clear background color. then add the button and your Bar to this view. and instead of adding The icons to your bar view add them to the containerView in a way that they overlap on the BarView